# Jersey JSON switching from camel case to underscores (snake case)

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey-2.0, camelcasing

I recently switched to jersey 2 ,.
I went through the documentation/web and got to know how to convert response class to custom class using `.readEntity(ClassName.class);`

But I am stuck at using `CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` naming strategy.

The current conversion fails as the response fields are with "_" and my POJO has Snake case .

Any help will be appreciated.

In jersey1 , I have been doing this :

```
MyResponse myResponse = client  
        .resource(url)
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .post(RequestClass.class, request);
```

the same I am not able to achieve post jersey 2 :
It gives compile time error when I as in above code :

I also tried :

```
MyResponse myResponse = client
        .target(getUrl())
        .request()
        .post(Entity.entity(request, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .readEntity(MyResponse.class);
```

but it's not creating `myResponse` object , cause the response I get has Snake_case response but my POJO has camel case fields.

Comment: Please showsme real code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is something that needs to be configured with the Jackson `ObjectMapper`. You can do this in a [`ContextResolver`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html). Basically, you need something like

```
@Provider
public class MapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public MapperProvider() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
                PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> cls) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Then register with your client

```
client.register(MapperProvider.class);
```

If you need this support on the server also, then you will need to register it on the server too.

Comment: this solved it . Thanks :) can't upvote the answer due to low reputation :(

Comment: How to we do this in unit testing?